# React Native Could not determine the dependencies of null

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

When I try to run it on android, I get the following mistake:

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > The new Java toolchain feature cannot be used at the project level in combination with source and/or target compatibility

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Might have something todo with the JDK you have installed. I would recommend installing JDK17 and trying to run it with that.

Comment: I already have JDK 17

Comment: @Aleksandra so from what i can see with your provided information you might have a dependency in your package.json that doesnt exist. Maybe run "npm update" and check if it works after that

Comment: thank you, I ran npm update, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem as you.
Try to run `npx react-native doctor`  to see if everything is fine.
At the beginning i had the wrong jdk version (v21) and it didnt work because it has to be older than v20. so i installed v17 and updated JAVA_HOME variable and didnt work either (but it's one stop closer).
i tried to create a new project again with `npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject` from react docs and it worked